# Fill index with C++ Standard Library

Tags: c++, indexing, std

Having some data in

```
struct Data {
    std::size_t some_other_data = 0;
    std::size_t id = 0;
};
```

which are stored in std::vector I want to create an index to elements by their `id` and append it to a larger index file.

In case I want to implement this with C++ Standard Library algorithm, which way should I follow?

Here is the code in "plain" C++ which does it:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

struct Data {
    std::size_t some_other_data = 0;
    std::size_t id = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> collected_indexes;

    std::vector<Data> dict = { { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    std::vector<std::size_t> index(dict.size());

    // The code I want to rewrite shorter with std
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < index.size(); ++i) {
        index[dict[i].id] = i;
    }

    collected_indexes.append_range(index);
    // End of code
}
```

It would be nice if the proposed solution could be used with [execution_policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) to make it parallel.

**Update**

People were confused with my question and were asking what exactly I am looking for. Here is the way I implemented this now (working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dqqbcaa65)):

```
    auto old_size = collected_indexes.size(); 
    collected_indexes.resize(collected_indexes.size() + dict.size()); 
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,dict.begin(), dict.end(), 
        [&](auto& dict_entry) { 
            std::size_t i = &dict_entry - dict.data();
            collected_indexes[old_size + dict[i].id] = i;
        });
```

But this durty hack is done with the sole purpose to ask, how this should be well-writted with usage of C++ Standard Library without 'ranges'.

I am sure that with usage of a proper algorithm this could be solved naturally without getting data from under the hood.

Comment: Maybe you should use a `std::unordered_map<std::size_t,Data>` instead for your dictionay? Where the key is the id of your Data item. Maps are usually the datastructure used for dictionaries.

Comment: Unfortunately, the C++ library contains only a few basic algorithms. [If the algorithm you're looking for is not here, it does not exist](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: OT, but what if one of elements has an id of 10 (or anything larger than `dict.size()`)?...

Comment: @PepijnKramer, performance is critical, so `std::unordered_map` with new/delete, etc. is out of the question; I moved from it in this task exactly after profiling. The structure is used in multithreading, and making `std::unordered_map` multithreading (or using existing concurrent unordered_map's)  is expensive. The size of the data is gigabytes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, this is about wording, most likely. I am not looking for ready algorithm, my question how to implement this with std. I was sure a combination of `std::transform` with lambda should work. Something like `auto old_size = collected_indexes.size(); collected_indexes.resize(collected_indexes.size() + dict.size()); std::transform(dict.begin(), dict.end(), collected_indexes.begin() + old_size, [&](auto& dict_entry) { return dict_entry.id;  });`

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade, it can't by precondition requirements, so no reason to check in code. This is the way how both `id` and `index` generated.

Comment: "*implement this with std*" Did you mean you want to create an std (range)  algorithm for the above-shown issue, that takes a range and returns a range that will contain custom  unary operation? If yes, wrap the `std::transform` sln to a template function.

Comment: you can simplify the code with ranges, or you can make it faster and multithreaded with openmp, you can't have both.

Comment: @JeJo, no I was sure that something like `auto old_size = collected_indexes.size(); collected_indexes.resize(collected_indexes.size() + dict.size()); std::transform(dict.begin(), dict.end(), collected_indexes.begin() + old_size, [&](auto& dict_entry) { return dict_entry.id;  });` should work. I am looking for something like this, very similar to the answer below, but with 'std', since I need parallel execution, which is still missing in 'ranges'.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, I don't ask about `ranges`. I am asking about `std` solution like 'auto old_size = collected_indexes.size(); collected_indexes.resize(collected_indexes.size() + dict.size()); std::transform(dict.begin(), dict.end(), collected_indexes.begin() + old_size, [&](auto& dict_entry) { return dict_entry.id;  });'

Comment: @DamirTenishev *I am asking about std solution like [...]* You already wrote it. Why doesn't it work? What is wrong with your `std::transform` sln?

Comment: @JeJo, the indirection is wrong. My "plain" C++ code jumps sparsely through index array based on values while `std::transform` expects to pass it linearly from begin to end. I need to reverse the algorithm somehow by moving through some dummy range from 1 to n and in lambda accessing the index array sparsely.

Comment: @JeJo, please see my **Update** section to the question. This code works, but it is ugly. Anyway, it shows the idea of the code I want to have. But I am still in two minds if this could be written shorter with some other algorithm instead of `std::for_each`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I updated the question with the **Update** section showing a hacky way to solve the problem with the purpose to explain what I meant with "solve with C++ Standard Library (what to call it shorter here?) algorithm". Can you please revisit and say if you see a better way to apply C++ STD LIB algorithms?

Comment: What comes to mind now is Scotty's quote from Star Trek III: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the drain". It seems that, quite often, self-proclaimed C++ uberhackers often try to out-do themselves in coming up as complicated concoctions as possible in order to accomplish the simplest possible tasks. The only practical purpose of them is bragging rights: after all, the more convoluted the code is, the more of a C++ expert its writer must be, right?

Comment: @DamirTenishev see the last update to my answer.

Comment: @DamirTenishev if your only objection to `ranges` is the lack of parallelism, take a look at this example: https://godbolt.org/z/13n88GM1n It uses `std::for_each` for parallel execution, but takes advantage of `std::views::enumerate` from c++23 to create indices.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the only goal is to learn how to implement things with C++STDLIB in straightforward way. When I write a loop and in the code review somebody comes and replaces 7 lines with one `std::transform` with `std::bind` and couple of predicates and then asks "Why don't you reuse C++STDLIB", I am wrong. When I try to check that there is no such a way/algorithm, I am wrong again. Where is the golden mean? When I say "my code is simple" people say "forgot about loops, see the ranges and pipes, we no more think in loops", etc., etc...

Comment: It looks like you're discovering the Golden Rule Of C++: if you ask ten C++ developers what is the best way to do <X>, you will get at least eleven different answers.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, so what is your approach to learn building-blocks-style libraries like stdlib **in action** if not trying to implement code with it? Do you just read books or imagine virtually how would it work? People show short, concise and very readable solutions both with ranges, views, pipes and I want to follow. What's wrong in trying to apply new approaches to simple tasks to see the way it works (not in code, but in logic and approach)? I am used to try and make a decision if to use it, what is your approach?

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade, thank you. Please see my comment below your answer. One final step is left, if it is still possible.

Comment: Yes, when I was learning C++ I <gasp> <shock> read textbooks. I opened Chapter 1, and started reading. Then Chapter 2, Chapter 3, and so on. At some point someone gains sufficient experience and knowledge to be able to learn things just by going through technical reference material, this is mostly how I updated my knowledge base up to C++20.  But if one starts out at the starting line, there are no shortcuts to using an organized, textbook-guided curriculum.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I am not at starting line. I read tons of books on C++ and even wrote one. I wrote tons of code which works in production. I am just learning new stuff in language in a way I used to: read specs for basics, read books for ideas, read code for better ideas, write code and see how it works. I don't see anything wrong with "try and get it" approach and can't see where your are leading to. Neither can I see what is wrong with trying and asking.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I've added it to my answer and re-arranged it so that the later versions are at the top

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade, thank you so much! That was exactly I was looking for. Let me wait till tomorrow for possible better solutions (as it is recommended on SO) and I would accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE**

As discussed in the comments, here is a hack-free version using `ranges` and operating directly on `collected_indices`. It also includes commented out alternative using parallel execution.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using std::execution::par_unseq;
namespace views = std::views;

struct Data
{
    std::size_t some_other_data;
    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dicts[2]
    {
        { { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } },
        { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 } }
    };
    std::vector<std::size_t> collected_indices;

    // The code I want to rewrite shorter with std
    for (auto&& [i, dict] : views::enumerate(dicts))
    {
        auto old_size = collected_indices.size();
        collected_indices.resize(old_size + dict.size());

        auto index = collected_indices | views::drop(old_size) | views::take(dict.size());        
        for (auto&& [j, e] : views::enumerate(dict)) index[e.id] = j;

        // parallel version
/*      auto view = views::enumerate(dict);
        std::for_each(par_unseq, view.begin(), view.end(),
            [&](auto&& e) { auto&& [i, d] = e; index[d.id] = i; }
       );
*/  }
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/86EWsWoa1

---

**UPDATE 3**

Here is the solution that uses `std::for_each` for parallel execution and `std::views::enumerate` from the `ranges` library to lazily create the index:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>  
#include <execution>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using std::execution::par_unseq;

struct Data
{
    std::size_t some_other_data;
    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dict { { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    std::vector<std::size_t> index(dict.size());

    // The code I want to rewrite shorter with std
    auto view = std::views::enumerate(dict);
    // or:
    // auto view = std::views::zip(std::views::iota(0u, dict.size()), dict);
    std::for_each(par_unseq, view.begin(), view.end(),
        [&](auto&& e) { auto&& [i, d] = e; index[d.id] = i; }
    );
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/dsEE3fG1T

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here is another solution using `std::for_each`. This is less hacky than your update, but is also slightly less efficient (since it has to create and fill the list of indices):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>  
#include <execution>
#include <vector>

using std::execution::par_unseq;

struct Data
{
    std::size_t some_other_data;
    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dict { { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    std::vector<std::size_t> index(dict.size()), is(dict.size());
    std::iota(is.begin(), is.end(), 0);

    // The code I want to rewrite shorter with std
    std::for_each(par_unseq, is.begin(), is.end(),
        [&](auto i) { index[dict[i].id] = i; }
    );
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/jv8Mn5Thh

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an example using `tbb`, as mentioned in the comments:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>  
#include <tbb/blocked_range.h>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <vector>

using range = tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>;

struct Data
{
    std::size_t some_other_data;
    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dict { { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    std::vector<std::size_t> index(dict.size());

    // The code I want to rewrite shorter with std
    tbb::parallel_for(range{0, dict.size()}, [&](range r) {
        for (auto i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) index[dict[i].id] = i;
    });
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Not much shorter, but maybe more readable (in my not-so-humble and extremely-biased opinion):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>  
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

namespace views = std::views;

struct Data
{
    std::size_t some_other_data;
    std::size_t id;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Data> dict { { 2, 2 }, { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    std::vector<std::size_t> index(dict.size());

    // The code I want to rewrite shorter with std
    for (auto&& [i, e] : views::enumerate(dict)) index[e.id] = i;
}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/Kx1xPrh8z

Comment: Thank you for the input, it helps, but the same goes as to the previous answer (above from *JeJo*), I am asking for the solution with `std`, not with `ranges`, since I want to benefit from parallel execution.

Comment: @DamirTenishev in your particular example parallel execution will most likely not help much due to expenses associated with spawning threads and synchronization. Unless there is some other processing that takes place, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: I see, but I want to give it a try and measure with profiler. In order to try, I need the code. So, the loop closes. :)

Comment: I can give you an example with parallel execution, but it won't be shorter... The reason why I chose `ranges` is that their algorithms takes the range, whereas `std` algos require `begin` and `end` iterators.

Comment: The loop has `par_unseq` and `i` is not an atomic variable. Would this code work at all or this will just lead to undefined behaviour? If not, why if `i` could be changed in parallel in many threads with unexpected results since it is not atomic?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Duh... you are right it won't work at all... :) Well, it did actually work for me because like I said earlier the compiler will execute it sequentially. But in general it won't. The only other option I can offer is using tbb

Comment: With tbb you mean tbb [concurrent_unordered_map](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/containers/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.html)? I already tried it, but it kills the performance since data size is huge (gigabytes) and using maps with new/delete/etc. is expensive.

Comment: You should have put all this data in your original question... :facepalm:

Comment: No, I was thinking of `parallel_for` with `blocked_range` which gives you needed indices.

Comment: I solved the problem with pure C++ Standard Library (see the **Update** section of my question), but this solution is still "hacky". Still looking if some other algorithm is more suitable here.

Comment: Thank you for the solution with tbb, it helps, so I upvoted, but I can't accept it, since the question is still about C++stdlib. I am not familiar much with `tbb::parallel_for` syntax, isn't what you posted use nested loops (one for tbb and one inside)?

Comment: Yes, you still need a loop inside `parallel_for` but `tbb` will "break up" your data and spawn multiple threads to keep your CPU busy. BTW, see my last update without using `tbb`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I meant with "dummy range from 1 to n" in my comment to @JeJo in my comments under my question, but my dict and index arrays are quite large as I wrote (gigabytes) and getting another one could lead to memory-bounding. Ranges would allow fictional dummy with `std::ranges::views::iota(1, 9);`, it would be nice to implement something similar here to avoid such memory consumption.

Comment: Thank you again! One extra question, I tried to raise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78030594/fill-index-with-c-ranges-views-and-pipes), is your recommended approach with the `for (auto&& [i, e] : views::enumerate(dict)) index[e.id] = i;`  best in terms of that question (making piped version) or this is just a first-came-to-mind piped solution or the "best" one? I am asking because I feel that this could be solved more elegantly, like `collected_indexes.append_range(dict | std::views::transform(...));', but I can't see the way. Just curios for more elegant solution here.

Comment: I thought it was the most elegant solution (and somewhat pythonic if you know python). Unfortunately I can't get `.append_range()` to compile on godbolt...

Comment: It can easily be replaced with ['collected_indexes.insert(collected_indexes.end(), index.begin(), index.end());`](https://godbolt.org/z/3eP37x8xP) for the sake of this example.